# Using Config for api token gives error 'URI must be a string or UriInterface' Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I am trying to make an API call.

If I do this: `$url = "url-code.com?param1=value1&param2=value2&_token=enter-key-here";`
I don't get any error.

If I do this: `$url = "url-code.com?param1=value1&param2=value2&_token="+Config::get('app.john_doe_key');`

I get an error: 'URI must be a string or UriInterface'

## mycode

```
$statusCode = 200;
        $url = "url-code.com?param1=value1&param2=value2&_token="+Config::get('app.john_doe_key'); 

            $client = new Client();
            $res = $client->get($url);
            //dd($res);
            return $res->getBody();
```

**.env**

```
JOHN_DOE_APP_KEY=key
```

**config/app.php**

```
'john_doe_key' => env('JOHN_DOE_APP_KEY'),
```

Comment: Curious, what happens in your use the config helper? `config('app.john_doe_key')`? That being said, could you also show use the config file?

Comment: Seems `Config::get('app.john_doe_key')` is empty. What does it print?

Comment: Do you use + to append string?

Comment: @Jean-PhilippeMurray If I print Config('app.john_doe_key') I get the key result. I am adding the code of config and .env

Comment: Again, curiosity, but if you use `env('JOHN_DOE_APP_JEY')` does it get the required value? (Trying to figure out where things could go wrong here...)

Comment: @Yolo this outputs my key in the browser: return Config::get('app.john_doe_key');

Comment: @Jean-PhilippeMurray Yes both env and Config if returned to a view does show print the key.

Comment: At that point, I'd be curious to see the url with the parameters, is there any suspicious characters that could make things go wrong?

Comment: @Jean-PhilippeMurray Yes, url is wrong it outputs 864 instead of the whole url + param + key :/

Comment: I'm going to try and answer to this to help you, could you just confirm to me that the instance of Client is a Guzzle Client?

Comment: @Jean-PhilippeMurray url alone prints correctly and key alone prints correctly. if I concat then it prints first 3 characters of the key. That's the issue. Yes the instance is guzzle Client

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All right, based on our discussion in the comments of original question, here's what I would try.

Since everything in it's own works correctly, I would put all of the parameters in their own array:

```
$parameters = [
    'someParam' => 'value',
    'someOtherParam' => 'value',
    '_token' => Config::get('app.john_doe_key')
];
```

And use `http_build_query()` to correctly format them:

```
$formattedParameters = http_build_query($parameters);
```

And finally, build the URL with what I have:

```
$url = "http://url-code.com?{$formattedParameters}";
```

You should be having a correctly formatted URL to use with Guzzle at this point.

Comment: Can you have a look at this ques: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43306641/how-to-update-the-data-every-1-second-on-server-side-php-laravel it is based on same code. I would like to execute this every 1 second on server side. And I will be creating an RESTful Api to access this data in my application.